# Arduino Audio Sensor: AnalogOutput (A0) returns same value

Tags: audio, arduino, sensors, stm32

I would like to know why my *Keyes KY037 (KY038)* audio sensor returns me always same value which is in my opinion value of Vcc scaled to threshold value... It always returns me constant value that varies about +/- 3 on range [0 - 2^12-1].

I have done test with my ADC conversion (connected analog in on Vcc, GND respectively and I received ~10 and ~2100 because my threshold is set on that value of about 2100, that is reference level) and ADC conversion test worked fine, so problem is somewhere with Analog Out pin from audio sensor.

I can not see any difference on loud, or silent tone, feels like my audio sensor is not reacting on environment, it just prints same value.

I am using stm32f4 microcontroller board, but I don't think that that could be problem. I am doing ADC value reading after each 1 milisecond, MCU clock frequency is set on 150MHz.

Feel free to ask about any information which may be relevant to this issue.

Comment: 1) twiddle with potentiometer to get values somewhere in the middle of ADC range 2) check solder joints for "cold joints" (last time it wasn't just pot position but one of its wires wasn't soldered properly)

Comment: Use a multimeter to measure the output of the sensor. If that's equal to the value you get, then the problem is in the sensor, not the board.

Comment: Wait, how many pins do you have on the sensor? three or four? Then I think that STM32F4 uc have a 3.3V supply, so beware of 5V...

Comment: @frarugi87 audio sensor has 4 pins (A0, G, +, D0)

Comment: Ok, so you are reading the A0 pin.. If you have an oscilloscope try reading the voltage there, otherwise try seeing what happens on pin D0. For instance in a silent room turn it all the way clockwise, then start turning it in the opposite direction until the D0 pin changes state. leave it still for some seconds to check that it remains in that state, then make a loud noise (clap your hands, for instance). It should change state. If it doesn't, repeat the experiment turning the potentiometer the other way

Comment: @frarugi87 I have connected my DO on my analog in, and it detected successfully clap by changing from logical 0 (around 10 volts) to logical 1 (around 4090 volts).  I have connected my loudspeakers (with wire) on analog in, and it detected successfully voltage during song, it varied from about 10 - 1800.

Comment: @luka032 10 volts on a digital pin? Can you confirm this and tell me how you connected everything? anyway if when clapping it changes the sensor is working... Try measuring with an oscilloscope what happens on the analog pin

Comment: @frarugi87 My mistake it was 10/4096 ad converter result, I will reply in few days when I get to oscilloscope to measure that analog pin